# How do I resolve "ERR CERT COMMON NAME INVALID" page after visiting my Firebase hosting web app (no custom URL)?

Tags: firebase, ssl-certificate, firebase-hosting

I have a personal website: [https://www.${DOMAIN-NAME}.web.app](https://www.$%7BDOMAIN-NAME%7D.web.app) (advertising my real site may annoy some people)

This web app is working fine on my devices. I sent this link to my friend and it's showing him "ERR CERT COMMON NAME INVALID" error page. He is on a very secure computer.

Here is a screenshot of the error page:

[image: error page on google chrome]

I found one solution to this along with a process to recreate this error page. I went on a new device that has never visited my web app. Then, I wrote [http://www.${DOMAIN-NAME}.web.app](http://www.$%7BDOMAIN-NAME%7D.web.app) ("http" here) and got this error page. Changing from "http" to "https" here doesn't help. However, I solved this by closing the tab, and writing [https://www.${DOMAIN-NAME}.web.app](https://www.$%7BDOMAIN-NAME%7D.web.app) on a new tab. This immediately establishes the green secure lock.

However, this didn't help my friend. Is there something that I don't know that's causing this issue? I'll await any helpful answers. Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a `www.` in front of a Firebase Hosting `.web.app` domain. That's why you're seeing invalid cert. Try just `https://${DOMAIN-NAME}.web.app`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm contacting Firebase support. I think it will be annoying for people to get the error page just for writing "http://" as a prefix.

Comment: Actually I misread the question -- you need to remove the `www`.

Comment: I notice that you're right. But why? That doesn't seem proper for a website.

Comment: There's nothing inherent about `www` for websites - it was a popular convention but has no actual effect. The reason it's not available in this case is due to SSL certificates. Since each Firebase Hosting site has its own subdomain, there is a "wildcard" SSL certificate `*.web.app` for all sites. SSL certs can't have multiple segments (e.g. `*.*.web.app`) so it's not possible to apply the same cert to multiple levels of subdomains.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Michael. What you said here makes perfect sense to me. I hope you have a great day!

Comment: This also explains the reason when you attempt to setup a cname record of "www" on Google Domains, that points to a firebase site, that www..... does not work.  Many Thanks!